# How to put water mark on image which retrieved from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, blob

I need some help.

Below is my code that retrieving all the images stored in my database, if it runs the first block of code saved as **index.php** it is displaying but i want to put watermark after i've retrieved i.e; before displaying those images. Is that possible to integrate watermarks after or we can only do that before?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while( $result = mysql_fetch_array($query) ){
$id = $result['id'];
echo "<img src=img.php?id=$id>";
?>
```

and in img.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$image1 = $image['image'];
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
echo $image1;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Comment: But... Do you know how to add watermarks to images not retrieved from MySQL? The source of images looks fairly irrelevant IMHO...

Comment: try this one http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php use imagecreatefromstring()

Comment: No guys i don't know how to put watermark on normal image too. I'm very new to php, but after i've seen php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php example i understood the process of keeping watermark to a normal picture that in a folder. but what about the image i've retrieved from database i.e; $image1 = $image['image']; in my example..... i'm trying but not working. can u guys suggest me any ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing images as links and not blobs. But because of existing image database the following code will put a watermark on an image stored as a blob. It uses PDO instead of mysql_ functions which are deprecated.

```
<?php
function ImageStringCenter($image, $fontSize, $lineNumber, $totalLines, $text, $color ) { 
    $centerX = ceil( ( imagesx($image) - ( ImageFontWidth($fontSize) * strlen($text) ) ) / 2 ); 
    $centerY = ceil( ( ( imagesy($image) - ( ImageFontHeight($fontSize) * $totalLines ) ) / 2)  + ( ($lineNumber-1) * ImageFontHeight($fontSize) ) ); 
    ImageString($image, $fontSize, $centerX, $centerY, $text, $color ); 
} 
require("dbinfo.php");
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

$id = 1;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$image1 = $image['image'];
//Use imagecreatefrompng,imagecreatefromgif, imagecreatefromjpeg ,etc for othertypes
$im = imagecreatefromstring($image1);////For blobs
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 266, 266, 266);
ImageStringCenter($im, 5, 1, 2,  "Watermark", $text_color);
ImageStringCenter($im, 5, 2, 2,  "20/02/2013", $text_color);
header("Content-Type: image/png");//blob .png file
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($image1);
?>
```

**Database**

[image: database]

**Watermark on image**

[image: watermark]

Comment: Thanks for the code, i copied entire code which u've provided and changed he database and sql connection details and given particular id but it gave output as "image ../image.php cannot be displayed because it contains errors" please give reply.

Comment: In my code image needs to be type .png for imagecreatefrompng. For other types use imagecreatefromgif, imagecreatefromjpeg ,etc

Comment: This time it showed empty blank images, i changed as u said from imagecreatefrompng to imagecreatefromjpeg coz my images in database are jpg and stored in longblob and content type also changed from image/png to image/jpeg, then it's showing empty images.... whatj'

Comment: As I said in answer the code works with links to files,NOT blobs.See database schema. Always store meta data about the images (filename, location,etc) in the database, and store images externally in the file system. There is very little benefit of actually storing images in an SQL database.  They are very inconvenient to use when in a database.

Comment: Around 10,000 images were stored into my database into longblob format, so i can only apply watermark after i retrieve from database. is there any solution for my problem ?

Comment: @avinash Change `imagecreatefromjpeg($image1)`to `$im = imagecreatefromstring($image1)`. I will update my answer